# How does the file host change urls?

Tags: file, url, host

view-source:http://online.watchop.com/s/medias.php?id=op602.mp4

Hey, I'm viewing the source for the link above, anf if you refresh it every second you notice that that source file url changes everytime. I was wondering what kind of code is behind that/how it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonable thing to assume is that the PHP script that generates the page queries an index script whose job is to provide a URL from a pool of equivalent URLs for a given file. Those equivalent URLs are generated when the file is uploaded to the server(s) - or at least about that time.

That index returns the URL it chooses every time it's asked by the PHP script. One strategy could be to evenly divide visitors between servers - assuming each possible URL goes to a different server. One other strategy could be to send visitors to the least loaded server at that moment.

In any case, the returned value probably becomes a variable in the PHP script and that variable is echoed as the source URL for the appropriate HTML element.